# Win8 ComboBox IsDropDownOpen + Visibility causes Glitched UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am developing a Windows 8 App using XAML and C#.
I have a problem with my ComboBox, and have a simple example to demonstrate it.

1. Add the following to a Layout Aware Page (New BasicPage)

   ```
   <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" DropDownClosed="comboBox1_DropDownClosed" Visibility="Collapsed" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="179,217,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="998" Height="51">
       <x:String>Option 1</x:String>
       <x:String>Option 2</x:String>
       <x:String>Option 3</x:String>
   </ComboBox>
   <Button Click="Button_Click" Margin="585,130,0,416" Grid.Row="1" Height="82" Width="154">
       <Viewbox>
           <TextBlock Text="Press Me" />
       </Viewbox>
   </Button>
   ```
2. Add this to the page's CodeBehind

   ```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       comboBox1.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
       comboBox1.IsDropDownOpen = true;
   }

   private void comboBox1_DropDownClosed(object sender, object e)
   {
       comboBox1.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
   }
   ```

**Expected:**
When the button is pressed, the ComboBox should appear and the options should expand, allowing the user to select one. Once the user has selected an option, the ComboBox disappears.

**Actual Result:**
When the button is pressed, nothing happens. If the button is pressed a second time, the ComboBox appears in a glitched state, and the app is essentially non-responsive. (All input is directed at the ComboBox, which never closes.

Note: The DropDownClosed event fires immediately after the Button_Click event does. Removing the event handler doesn't change anything, but it's interesting that the DropDownClosed event is firing.

**Rejected Solution:**
It was suggested to me to use `Dispatcher.RunAsync` to set `IsDropDownOpen` after the `Visibility` change has taken effect. This seems to be a race condition, because it only works *some* of the time. **If there were a way to confirm that the ComboBox had been rendered visible,** adding this check to the RunAsync method could solve the problem.

As a workaround, I'm currently delaying Dispatcher.RunAsync for 200 milliseconds, which is an annoying workaround. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is there no `Xaml` `Triggers` in `Metro`? seems odd to drag UI logic into code behind

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you need to make sure `comboBox1` is actually rendered visible, before trying to set `IsDropDownOpen`. The way to do it is to make the second call via `Dispatcher`:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
    Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => comboBox1.IsDropDownOpen = true);
}
```

Comment: +1. This seems to work for me, and is probably a much better answer than mine. I'm curious as well on why this problem exists in the first place. Any further thoughts on why your solution works, or can you at least point me to some documentation?

Comment: This does not solve my issue. I'm familiar with `Dispatcher.RunAsync`, but I believe this solution is incomplete. Obviously, setting the `Visibility` property doesn't synchronously return only once the `ComboBox` has rendered, and I doubt that the task for rendering the `ComboBox` is guaranteed to complete before my dispatched call to `IsDropDownOpen`. Do I misunderstand? Perhaps there's a way to confirm that the ComboBox has been rendered: either a test on `comboBox1`/`Frame`, or a better understanding of UI Task scheduling, or setting `IsDropDownOpen` from a Rendered event or similar?

Comment: @chuex Unfortunately I didn't come across any documentation on the subject, although I'd be very interested in it as well. I have used this approach in similar situations before and it always worked for me. I don't have any definite proof but my understanding is that `Dispatcher.RunAsync` schedules the call on the UI thread while `CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal` means it is going to be processed in the order it was scheduled. Asuming that `Visibility` setter also schedules the rendering to the UI thread with normal priority, the calls should always be processed in the right order.

Comment: @Nathan Is there a case when it doesn't work for you, i.e. have you encountered a race condition? Or do you just doubt the solution will always work correctly? I'm really interested to know since as I've already mentioned in the above comment this approach has worked for me in similar situations.

Comment: The above solution works for a simple case, but it doesn't work in my actual app. Perhaps my simple example is too simple. In my actual app, despite using `Dispatcher.RunAsync`, the glitched UI sometimes appears as if I had not used `Dispatcher.RunAsync`. But, as I mentioned, after delaying the dispatched method with `await Task.Delay(200);` before setting `IsDropDownOpen`, the glitch hasn't occurred yet. Doesn't this strongly suggest a race condition?

Comment: @Nathan Well, it does. Unless there's something else affecting the behavior in your case, I might indeed be missing something in my simplified understanding of UI scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

What a nasty bug, ah?

A simple workaround is instead of using the Visibility property, use Opacity. It works as expected:

```
   <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" DropDownClosed="comboBox1_DropDownClosed" Opacity="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="179,217,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="998" Height="51">
        <x:String>Option 1</x:String>
        <x:String>Option 2</x:String>
        <x:String>Option 3</x:String>
    </ComboBox>


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        comboBox1.Opacity = 1;
        comboBox1.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    }

    private void comboBox1_DropDownClosed(object sender, object e) {
        comboBox1.Opacity = 0;
    }
```

Cheers!

Comment: Nathan will tell if this workaround fits him. `Visibility = Collapsed` is not exactly the same as `Opacity = 0`, but it might be close enough. Anyway, I'm more interested in getting to the bottom of the original issue than finding workarounds for it :)

Comment: Thanks Andre, I think this may work for now. Of course, it forces me to hide the control in some other way because I can still tap a transparent ComboBox, and it causes Auto-sizing `Grid`s to reserve space. I agree with Damir, I'd prefer to have a working `Visibility`, but this seems to be a great alternative to a 200ms delay.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the following on my desktop and Surface device, and it seems to work all the time.  It is a variation on delaying setting `IsDropDownOpen`.  I understand you may have tried some variation of this that produced a race condition. I am not seeing a race condtion, so hopefully it works for you as well.

```
// need this for Task
using System.Threading.Tasks;
...

// note async keyword added to function signature
async private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
    // add small delay before opening dropdown
    await Task.Delay(1);
    comboBox1.IsDropDownOpen = true;
}
```